# Identifying an old kids' book with a two part-cover, one with a boy covered in scales

Tags: story-identification

The story almost completely escapes me, but the cover does not.  The cover was two sheets of cardboard one on top of the other.  Basically it was an inside cover and outside cover.  On the top cover was a picture of a normal boy of about 12 years of age (holding a stick) with cut-outs for his eyes to allow you to see the cover below. On the under-cover was the same boy in the same pose, but now he is covered in scales.

I read the book somewhere in the late 90's to early 2000's but as to when it was published, I doubt in was any older than the mid 80's.  If I had to guess, I would say it was aimed for the YA audience (I read it as a set work in school in South Africa if that helps).

Also, for what it is worth, the only part of the story I remember is a description of the boy's father's flyswatter, which was stained with fly blood from overuse.

Pretty scant information, I know, but I have seen amazing things done on this site with less information.

Comment: I'm sure you can do better than this. Have a look at [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) to see if the checklist jogs your memory.

Comment: When did you read this? Was the cover highly unusual (two outside covers on one side)? How old was the boy?

Comment: Thanks for the link @Valorum.  It was highly enlightening.  I hope my additional information helps.

Comment: Sounds like a book in the Animorphs series, possibly *[The Invasion](https://animorphs.fandom.com/wiki/The_Invasion)*. All the covers in the series were double covers like that.